# SharePoint sharing invitation - users shouldn't see each other

Tags: external-users, external-sharing

When adding a user to a group the default option is to send an invite by email. While this is great it's by no means great that the invite is sent as a single mail with all users in the "To" field in plain text.

When sharing with external users we really don't want them to know who else we shared the info with. I have handled on the site itself by setting the correct permission, but that obviously don't affect the email.

Any tricks for me running a SharePoint Online version? Obviosly I need a solution which does not require me to hardcode all possible future users. I need a solution that works for all future users without specifying them individually.

Answer (score -1):

You may achieve that using powershell as below:

```
Set-SPOTenant -BccExternalSharingInvitationsList "jim@email.com" -BccExternalSharingInvitations $true
```

When the `BccExternalSharingInvitations` feature is enabled, all external sharing invitations that are sent will blind copy the e-mail messages listed in the BccExternalSharingsInvitationList.

```
BccExternalSharingInvitationsList
```

> Specifies a list of e-mail addresses to be BCC'd when the BCC for
>   External Sharing feature is enabled. Multiple addresses can be
>   specified by creating a comma separated list with no spaces.

[MSDN Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Set-SPOTenant?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thank you. But that would require me to add all blind copies to the list correct? I need every and all invitations sent from SharePoint to be blind copies no matter who I'm sending to.

Comment: All, you have to do is provide email addresses of external users to be blind copied and set the `BccExternalSharingInvitations ` true

Comment: So it does require me to know the adresses of all possible future users. That's hardly a solution.